# How to dynamically determining carrierwave uploader column name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have some meta-programming that condenses multiple direct S3 upload processes into a single controller.  Then, those actions are shared across many models.  To accomplish this, among many other details, I need to know the column name of a given models uploader.  I facilitate this by having an 'uploader_name' method in each of my models that use the shared actions.  For example, I have an Expense model that has a receipts uploader...

```
def uploader_name
  'receipt'
end 

mount_uploader :receipt, ReceiptUploader
```

So, now I can call Expense.new.uploader_name to return a string, or in a shared action I would use @obj.send(@obj.uploader_name) to get the uploader object (where @obj is any one of the affiliated models using the shared actions).  This works fine.  However, I think I can clean it up.  One way that would help me refactor is not needing the uploader_name method.  Or, being able to use a single uploader_name method in a shared module that is able to dynamically determine the column name of the uploader.

Is there a method within Carrierwave where I can access the column name on a models uploader without know what the uploader is called?  Since the module is shared across multiple classes, i have to figure it out dynamically---I have read through the carrierwave, but not finding a solution.

Something like this...for example:

```
obj = self.class.name
obj.new.uploader # would return the mounted :receipts uploader
obj.new.uploader_column # would return the uploader column, in this case :receipt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods provided by the uploader class.  So, to solve this I just delegate the :mounted_as method from the uploader to the class that calls it.  Then, without knowing the name of the actual uploader I can just call self.mounted_as.to_s to return the name of the uploader.

So, for a User model with an avatar uploader I do this.

```
class User    
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  delegate :mounted_as, to: :avatar
```

So, if I call @user.mounted_as I get :avatar.  Or, more importantly...if I call self.mounted as I get :avatar when self is a User.  I have a module that is shared between all models that use an uploader.  In that module I include

```
def uploader_name
  self.mounted_as.to_s
end
```

Now, I can do some meta-programming since I do not know who self is, and I do not know what self's uploader is called.  But, now I can get access to both dynamically.  This is helpful because I can share one uploader controller and one uploader form across multiple classes who use an uploader.

I can also do things like pass accepted extensions to the form input (see html5 accepts option) by simply grabbing the extensions in the uploader's extension_whitelist method.

```
self.send(uploader_name).extension_whitelist
# this is dynamically getting @user.avatar.extension_whitelist
# or @company.logo.extension_whitelist
```

I can also set uploader attributes using, for example...

```
obj.send(obj.uploader_name).content_type = 'image/jpeg'
# this is dynamically setting @user.avatar.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
# or @company.logo.content_type = 'image/jpeg'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
obj.class.uploaders.keys.first
=> :receipt
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/mount.rb#LC20